# Анимация SVG при наведение на родительский блок

Tags: css, svg, svg-animation, hover

У меня есть карточка у нее есть стрелка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
            <svg width="25" height="16" viewBox="0 0 25 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M24.7071 8.70711C25.0976 8.31658 25.0976 7.68342 24.7071 7.29289L18.3431 0.928932C17.9526 0.538408 17.3195 0.538408 16.9289 0.928932C16.5384 1.31946 16.5384 1.95262 16.9289 2.34315L22.5858 8L16.9289 13.6569C16.5384 14.0474 16.5384 14.6805 16.9289 15.0711C17.3195 15.4616 17.9526 15.4616 18.3431 15.0711L24.7071 8.70711ZM0 9H24V7H0V9Z" fill="#748198" />
            </svg>
```

При наведение на родительский блок я хочу получить такую стрелку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<svg width="65" height="16" viewBox="0 0 65 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Изначально пробовал через псевдо элемент подставлять линию и при наведение я у svg менял fill и анимировал псевдо элемент, но столкнулся с проблемами при изменение ширины экрана псевдо элемент съезжал

```
.stages-item__icon{
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #748198;
    transition: width 0.5s;
  }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать как анимировать саму svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на `css` (без `svg`)

```css
:root {
  --arrow-bg: #748198;
  --arrow-bg-hover: #00ACD3;
  --arrow-width: 2rem;
  --arrow-width-hover: 5rem;
  --arrow-height: .175rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.icon-arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--arrow-width);
  height: var(--arrow-height);
  background-color: var(--arrow-bg);
  border-radius: var(--arrow-height);
  transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
}

.icon-arrow::before,
.icon-arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: .8rem;
  height: var(--arrow-height);
  background-color: var(--arrow-bg);
  transform: translateY(.05rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: right center;
  border-radius: var(--arrow-height);
  transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

.icon-arrow::after {
  transform: translateY(-.05rem) rotate(-45deg);
}

.block:hover .icon-arrow {
  width: var(--arrow-width-hover);
}

.block:hover .icon-arrow,
.block:hover .icon-arrow::before,
.block:hover .icon-arrow::after {
  background-color: var(--arrow-bg-hover);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="icon-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Рисуем path и вставляем marker и при наведении на rect т.е mousemove подменяем d у path как убрали курсор ставим path d на место и всё

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 50" width="300">
  <defs>
    <style>
      path{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        transition: 0.34s cubic-bezier(0, 1.54, 0.99, 0.1);
      }
    </style>
    <marker id="arrow" 
      viewBox="0 0 10 10"
      refX="5"
      refY="5"
      markerWidth="8"
      markerHeight="8"
      orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <path d="M-20,-20 5,5 -14,24"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <rect class="js_rect" width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent"/>
  <path class="js_path" d="M5,24 100,24"  marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
  
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
   document.querySelector(".js_rect").onmousemove = function (){
     document.querySelector(".js_path").setAttribute("d", "M5,24 250,24")
   }
     document.querySelector(".js_rect").onmouseout = function (){
      document.querySelector(".js_path").setAttribute("d", "M5,24 100,24")
   }
  ]]></script>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в вашем случае можно анимировать path внутри svg. Движение и цвет - вообще элементарно:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

svg path {
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

div:hover svg path {
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  fill: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="150" height="16" viewBox="0 0 25 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M24.7071 8.70711C25.0976 8.31658 25.0976 7.68342 24.7071 7.29289L18.3431 0.928932C17.9526 0.538408 17.3195 0.538408 16.9289 0.928932C16.5384 1.31946 16.5384 1.95262 16.9289 2.34315L22.5858 8L16.9289 13.6569C16.5384 14.0474 16.5384 14.6805 16.9289 15.0711C17.3195 15.4616 17.9526 15.4616 18.3431 15.0711L24.7071 8.70711ZM0 9H24V7H0V9Z" fill="#748198" />
            </svg>
</div>
```

Но чтобы изменить форму стрелки (удлинить хвостик), нужно менять сам path.